# IE Strikes Again!

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, browser

I have been working on a basic site for my family's recycling yard store.

One page in particular has had me stumped for two weeks.

It works perfectly in every browser, except Internet Explorer!
I have tested it in Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Flock, Opera, SeaMonkey, RockMelt and the javascript content works perfectly.

However, in IE the page loads, is not centered and javascript doesn't work.
I have JS turned on and other pages work in IE, just not this one.

Can anyone shed some light on what I have done wrong?

The link is http://actionrecyclers.co.nz/Testing/Recyclers/store.php

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

OK, it won't let me delete my wrongly posted answers below.

Thank you for help on the centering problem.

Does anyone have any ideas why scripts won't load. Sorry I can't be more helpful.
What I am especially trying to find out is why the selects are populated with categories in all other browsers, except IE. I know that there is over 200 lines of code, so any tips or pointers that can help set me in the right direction would be very helpful.

---

Here are some images in case it helps.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYlkm.jpg

And the other image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYlkm.jpg

Comment: Which version(s) of IE does it not work on? Also, you have 245 lines of code; please narrow down the problem as much as possible -- be specific. "javascript doesn't work" is difficult to help debug ;-)

Comment: @jacques , some home margin:auto is not working , let me debug more

Comment: @jacques something wrong with your layout , margin auto on left and right should work in IE also, let me debug more

Comment: @jacques , why did you gave relative for all the elmenets , you gave relative at the root leve.

Comment: @gov I added the root level relative later and haven't removed the lower level ones yet. Do you think they could have something to do with the problems?

Comment: @jacques , please remove it if you don't need it , unless you have some animations or someother absolute divs positioned relative to parent.

Comment: Just did, I think. Anything else?

Comment: @jacques got the problem , you don't standard doctype on your file , firefox works fine, but IE falls back to quirks mode and breaking alignnment, add proper doctype at the start of your page , it should fix the problem

Comment: BTW Kudos to DreamInCode for creating such an awesome community, far friendlier and more helpful than other forums I have tried in the past.

Comment: @jacquies , did that fix your problem , if so you can mark my answer as correct...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

acques got the problem , you don't `standard doctype` on your file , firefox works fine, but IE falls back to `quirks mode` and breaking alignnment, add proper doctype at the start of your page , it should fix the problem

change width to 100% its working on IE too

```
.center {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```